# Install db2 express c on Mac OSX

Tags: db2, mac-os-x

I have posted the question yesterday, then I was able to figure it out by myself. As I haven't found any complete guide, I'm writing down the steps just in case.

So the question is: "How do I install db2 express c on Mac OS X?".

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to edit/create the /etc/sysctl.conf and insert the following:

```
 kern.sysv.shmmax=1073741824                                                                                                                                                 
 kern.sysv.shmmin=1
 kern.sysv.shmmni=4096
 kern.sysv.shmseg=32
 kern.sysv.shmall=1179648
 kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
 kern.maxfiles=65536
```

reboot. Then google db2 express c mac osx and download db2 express c 9.5.2 for mac osx. Once downloaded uncompress the file

```
tar -xzvf db2exc_952_MAC_x86_64.tar.gz
```

enter the exp directory and start the installation wizard as root

```
cd exp
sudo ./db2setup
```

before continuing you need to create 2 users, one for administration purposes and another one as instance owner. For the second user name use no more than 8 characters and use just letters, otherwise the node name won't be accepted later on. Follow the installation wizard steps: enter the username for the DAS and for the instance owner. Once the installation is complete, you need to switch to the instance owner (dbuser in our case):

```
su dbuser
```

add the following line to your .bashrc file:

```
. ~/sqllib/db2profile
```

exit and relogin. If everything went well you should be able to start db2 (as a root) and create the SAMPLE database

```
sudo db2start
db2sampl 
db2
```

That's it!

Comment: I have to wait two more days :)